# Рандомный пароль

Tags: python, idle

Я хочу сделать так,чтобы при нажатии на кнопку появлялись рандомные пароли в Python Shell

```
from random import *
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x200")

number = "123456789"
new_string = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
up_string = new_string.upper()
passw = number+new_string+up_string
List = list(passw)
shuffle(List)

user_passw = ''.join([choice(List) for x in range(8)])

def hello():
    print(user_passw)
button = Button(window, text="Click me", command=hello)


label = Label(window)
label.config(text='Enter Text', font='Arial 25', fg='gray')
label.pack(padx=50, pady=20)

button = Button(window, text="Click me", command=hello)
button.config(text="Click me", bg='black', fg='red', font="Arial 15",width=20, height=5)

button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: И в чем вопрос/проблема?

Comment: Не заменяйте текст вопроса совершенно другим вопросом, вместо этого создайте отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

так же можете использовать специально для создания более рандомных значений `secrets`

```
import secrets
import string

name = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

print("".join([secrets.SystemRandom().choice(name) for i in range(secrets.SystemRandom().randrange(8, 10))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью метода `sample` из модуля `random` получаем случайный список уникальных элементов из указанной последовательности. Затем преобразуем список в строку с помощью метода `join`

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import string

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x200")

def generate_password():
    symbols = string.digits + string.ascii_letters
    passw_len = 8
    password = ''.join(random.sample(symbols, passw_len))
    return password

def print_password():
    password = generate_password()
    print(password)

button = tk.Button(window, text="Click me", command=print_password)
button.config(text="Click me", bg='black', fg='red', font="Arial 15",width=20, height=5)

button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```